# INDEX builtin with input

Tags: jq

I'm trying to build an INDEX from a json file which contains a list of flat objects.

If I use the construct

```
jq 'INDEX(.a + ":" + .b)' < data.json
```

I get what i want. But if I use

```
jq 'INDEX(input; .a + ":" + .b) data.json
```

then I get the error

```
jq: error (at data.json:<last-line>): break
```

The reason I need to use the second form is that I will then need to JOIN another `input` to the index of the first, and I don't see how to do that from STDIN.

Any ideas how I can get around this?

(Currently running jq-1.6 on MacOS 10.13.6)

Adding input (data.json):

```
[
    {
        "a": "a1",
        "b": "b1",
        "c": "c1",
        "d": "d1"
    },
    {
        "a": "a2",
        "b": "b2",
        "c": "c2",
        "d": "d2"
    },
    {
        "a": "a3",
        "b": "b3",
        "c": "c3",
        "d": "d3"
    }
]
```

And expected output

```
{
  "a1:b1": {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b1",
    "c": "c1",
    "d": "d1"
  },
  "a2:b2": {
    "a": "a2",
    "b": "b2",
    "c": "c2",
    "d": "d2"
  },
  "a3:b3": {
    "a": "a3",
    "b": "b3",
    "c": "c3",
    "d": "d3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add example input and output to your question.

Comment: @oguzismail : examples added

Comment: Note that this does not work in `jq` version 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `INDEX/2` should be a stream of the items to be indexed; here, `.[]` is exactly what we want:

```
INDEX(.[]; .a + ":" + .b)
```

Comment: You're right. That is EXACTLY what I want here. Many thanks.

Comment: Is there way to get the same result in jq v1.5 ?

Comment: @Yunk - One way would be to copy the def of INDEX. Just google with the terms: jq def builtin.jq

Answer (score 0):

For jq version 1.5 or older, `INDEX` does not seem to be working (does not exist?), but this works instead:

```
jq 'map({key: (.a + ":" + .b), value: .}) | from_entries' data.json
```